# Magento: Where would I place that functionality?

Tags: magento

I have a Magento form with a button and some fields. The button click calls a controller and in the controller I query the DB (using fetchAll) and create a csv file from the results.

Whats the best place to store the DB action and the CSV file creation? In a model maybe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a model, a resource model and a resource model collection for the data you need to export. In the collection I would define functionality that queries data from one or many (if necessary) tables . In the model itself I would create a function that fetches that collection and saves it into a CSV file. The controller action would contain only the model initialization and a call to the export function.

Comment: but where is the best place to store this .csv file?